# Chain Maven Repository to select local filesystem before remote server

Tags: maven

I am trying to chain maven to fetch dependencies from my local filesystem before it looks for them in the remote server.

**settings.xml**

```
<repository>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  <id>local</id>
  <name>libs-local-release</name>
  <url>file:///E:/project-folder/jars</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>libs-release</name>
  <url>https://www.repositoryURL.com/libs-release</url>
</repository>
```

**Console result for mvn verify -U**

```
Downloading from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://www.repositoryURL.com/libs-release/package/dependency/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from central: https://www.repositoryURL.com/libs-release/package/dependency/maven-metadata.xml (2.1 kB at 45 kB/s)
Downloading from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.007/dependency-1.0.0.007.pom
Downloaded from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.007/dependency-1.0.0.007.pom (4.3 kB at 287 kB/s)
Downloading from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.172/dependency-1.0.0.172.pom
Downloaded from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.172/dependency-1.0.0.172.pom (4.3 kB)
Downloading from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.173/dependency-1.0.0.173.pom
Downloaded from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.173/dependency-1.0.0.173.pom (4.3 kB)
Downloading from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.174/dependency-1.0.0.174.pom
Downloaded from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.174/dependency-1.0.0.174.pom (4.3 kB at 269 kB/s)
Downloading from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.175/dependency-1.0.0.175.pom
Downloaded from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.175/dependency-1.0.0.175.pom (4.3 kB)
Downloading from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.176/dependency-1.0.0.176.pom
Downloaded from local: file:///E:/project-folder/jars/package/dependency/1.0.0.176/dependency-1.0.0.176.pom (4.3 kB at 287 kB/s)
```

As you can see, Maven downloads dependencies from my filesystem and the server but the localRepository `(%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository)` seems to be updated with the dependency in the server instead of my filesystem.

How do I configure it so that local jar files (from filesystem repo) are preferred over the remote jar files?

Comment: So you want a file system cache of some Maven artifacts?

Comment: This is done by default with local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository` I don't understand what you are trying to achieve or what kind of problem you are trying to solve...

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, yes; A local filesystem cache sounds about right but a cache on top of the local repository at `$HOME/.m2/repository`.

Comment: Thats easy, just add a `file:///....` remote repository.  You need to populate it yourself though from another local repository.  If you describe what the problem is you are _actually_ trying to solve (in the question) you might get a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you want to achieve, but I try my best:

Maven has a dedicated local repository (the one you mentioned, `C:\%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository`). It always looks there first. No need to configure anything for that.

SNAPSHOT dependencies are an exception because they can change so Maven looks them up in remote repositories as well (periodically).

Everything that is downloaded from a remote repository is stored in the local repository so that on the next try, Maven does not need to download it again.

If you have jars you need, but which are in no Maven repository, you have several ways of handling this situation, depending on the number of jars, number of users etc.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I modified the question to better explain my situation. I am looking for the last scenario you described. I am looking for a method to fetch a jar file from the local filesystem instead of the remote repo. Nevertheless use the remote repo for other dependencies not in the local FS.

Comment: From the referred post, do I have to perform a `-DlocalRepositoryPath` even after setting up `local-maven-repo` in pom.xml? Also, the described case looks more like the file is available in the local repo but not in the remote repo. What if I have the file in both repos?

Comment: It is best to configure all this in your settings.xml. If the file is in both repos, why does not matter where you download it from? After the first download, it is available in your standard local repository.

Comment: I edit a package locally and before I publish it to the artifact. I wish to test it with another project which depends on the first package. I wish to set the build directory of the first package as a dependency for the project.

Comment: Never change an existing jar without changing the version. If you use something like 1.0-fixed instead of 1.0, you are fine and have no trouble with the order of the repositories.

Comment: Never edit a package locally cause this will bring you into hell...sorry to say that...testing an other project can simply being done by using the updated version number of better by using SNAPSHOT's...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I think I understand. I am probably using a wrong approach.